# preventDefault() not working in a input type text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This is my code:

```
$('#Login').keydown(function(e){         
        if(e.which  == 32){     
            alert("enter");
            this.preventDefault();            
        }        
    });
```

This code doesn't work but sends the alert:

```
$('#Pwd,#Pwd2').on('keydown',function(e){
        if(e.which == 32){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

And this code works.
I do not understand why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are wanting to prevent the default action of the `Event` (which is passed in as the parameter for your event function, you are calling it `e`).

`this` is the element that is the target of your event (ie: in this case `e.target` which will be your `#Login` element) and not an event itself, this does not have a `preventDefault()`.

Just use the `Event` object for this as well:

```
$('#Login').keydown(function(e){         
    if(e.which == 32){     
        e.preventDefault();            
    }        
});
```

With the above you'll see the event is cancelled every time you hit the space bar within `#Login`: http://jsfiddle.net/xWmUU/

Comment: @user2596216, I'm not sure what you mean. Why would you change "this" for "and"?

Answer (score 2):

`preventDefault` is a method of the Event object, so it makes sense that it works when called on an event.

`this` will refer to `#Login` in this case, which is a DOM object and will not have the `preventDefault` method.

Note that because of how event propagation works, `this` will not always be equal to `e.target`.